# DevExpress DataGrid: How to set the ItemSource of a GridControl in a DetailDescriptor

Tags: wpf, xaml, devexpress

I have a GridControl whose ItemSource is bound to SearchResultViewModel.SearchResults. In this GridControl i have a DetailDescriptor which contains another GridControl whose ItemSource i want to set to SearchResultViewModel.SearchResults too.

This is my Code:

```
<dxg:GridControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SearchResultViewModel.SearchResults, Mode=OneWay}">
        <dxg:GridControl.DetailDescriptor>
            <dxg:ContentDetailDescriptor>
                <dxg:ContentDetailDescriptor.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <dxg:GridControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SearchResultViewModel.SearchResults, Mode=OneWay}" MaxHeight="200">
                            <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                                <dxg:GridColumn Header="Heating Deviation" FieldName="HeatingDeviation"/>
                            </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                        </dxg:GridControl>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </dxg:ContentDetailDescriptor.ContentTemplate>
            </dxg:ContentDetailDescriptor>
        </dxg:GridControl.DetailDescriptor>
```

SearchResults Looks like this

```
public struct SearchResult
{
    public SearchResult(SepoContainer sepo, int heatingDeviation)
    {
        HeatingDeviation = heatingDeviation;
        SepoContainer = sepo;
    }

    public int HeatingDeviation { get; }

    public SepoContainer { get; }
}
```

I think I missunderstand something because I don't know how to proceed

Answer (score 0):

The `ContentDetailDescriptor.DataContext` is automatically set to the row object, you can achieve what you want by using `RelativeSource` in your `Binding` to retrieve the outter `GridControl`.

```
<dxg:ContentDetailDescriptor.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <dxg:GridControl ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=dxg:GridControl}, Mode=OneWay}" MaxHeight="200">
            <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                <dxg:GridColumn Header="Heating Deviation" FieldName="HeatingDeviation"/>
            </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
        </dxg:GridControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</dxg:ContentDetailDescriptor.ContentTemplate>
```